# Why am I not being able to use position 0 of an array with __proto__?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, console

I am not able to use an array that I have in the code. I have no idea why `__proto__` is there

[image]

It looks like a normal array, but when I want to access the values of position 0 (arr [0]), the console returns "undefined".

here is the javascript code:

```js
const apiUrl = 'https://api.covid19api.com/dayone/country/south-africa';
async function getData(){
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
  const data = await response.json();
  const arr = data.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.Confirmed ? [...acc, cur.Confirmed] : acc, []);
  return arr;
}

var res = [];
getData().then( val => {
  res.push(val);
})  

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
   

const apiUrl = 'https://api.covid19api.com/dayone/country/south-africa';
async function getData(){
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
  const data = await response.json();
  const arr = data.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.Confirmed ? [...acc, cur.Confirmed] : acc, []);
  return arr;
}

var res = [];
function showData(callback){
  getData().then( val => {
  res.push(val);
  callback();
    });
}
 
showData( function(){
  console.log(res[0])
});
```

Here's another solution, almost the same as TmasYIN's. you can add a callback function that's executed inside .then() function, and that callback function is defined when you execute showData.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the line `console.log(res);` is finished faster than the function `getData()`.

```js
const apiUrl = 'https://api.covid19api.com/dayone/country/south-africa';
async function getData(){
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
  const data = await response.json();
  const arr = data.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.Confirmed ? [...acc, cur.Confirmed] : acc, []);
  return arr;
}

var res = [];
getData().then( val => {
  res.push(val);
  console.log(res);
  console.log(res[0]);
})
```

Put the statement inside the function `getDate()` or use `.then()` again to handle the data afterward.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense! Thank you.
The problem I'm having now is that I can't access res[0] from other part of the code.

Comment: You can put those related function after the function getData() with .then(). For example, getData().then(...).then(...) @martoxx99

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
   

const apiUrl = 'https://api.covid19api.com/dayone/country/south-africa';
async function getData(){
  const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
  const data = await response.json();
  const arr = data.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.Confirmed ? [...acc, cur.Confirmed] : acc, []);
  return arr;
}

function showData(callback){
  getData().then( val => {
  res.push(val);
  
    });
  setTimeout(function() {
        
       callback();
        
    }, 1500);
  
}
 
showData( function(){
  console.log(res[0])
});
```

*proto* is a built-in javascript object's inheritance pointer that points to its parent. (In javascript, function is also an object). In your example, getData() is inherited from AsyncFunction, so if you call getData().*proto*, it gives you an object of AsyncFunction.  You can get the result after you give it some time to fetch data.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! I just tried that code, but I still have the same problem. When I want to access res [0], I get undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the result of a promise (i.e. its fulfilled value) immediately after registering a handler on a promise, because promise code *never* calls handlers provided to it synchronously.

When a promise becomes resolved or rejected, promise code puts jobs to execute handlers (and monitor their behavior) in a promise job queue, leaving executing tasks from the queue to the event loop manager.

This demonstration shows data is not transferred by `then` in the same call out from the event loop, but can be available after returning to the event loop:

```js
let dataPromise = new Promise( resolve => resolve("hello, I'm data"));

var res=[];
res.ready = false;

dataPromise.then(data => {
   res.push(data);
   res.ready = true;
});

function processData() {
   console.log(
     "ready: %s", data: %s",
     res.ready, res[0]);
}
processData(); // won't work

setTimeout( processData, 20); // will work
```

Data obtained using a promise is only available through the Promise interface. Code using the data can register a call back on the data promise by calling the `then` method of the promise, or using `await` before the promise inside an `async` function.

Obviously in a practical application, data also won't be available from a server request until after the server has responded, the browser received the reply and notified script code of the outcome.